# Getting 'couldn't send retry' error in web chat for questions which are not present in knowledge base

Tags: c#, azure, azure-bot-service, web-chat

I created a bot with Azure in C#. This bot is working fine for question which are present in my knowledge base. But when I try different question, it gives error `couldn't send retry` below that question and reply to that question as `Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.` 
It should reply `No match found` instead of `Sorry, my bot code is having an issue`.
One more issue is this bot sometimes gives random answer form KB for some questions which are not present in Kb instead of `No answer found in KB`.

In web chat channel, it shows following issue - `There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError`. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using one of the samples? If so, which one? If not, can you show me which line of code you're receiving the error on? It may help to run the bot locally, in Emulator, to debug this.

Comment: I've added an answer. If this is not your issue, let me know and I will update it.

Comment: I created a bot in C# in Azure and changed `BasicLuisDialog.cs` file according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis) document. For some question (which are not in Kb), I am getting correct reply -`Not found in KB` and for some questions, getting above error. My bot's files are here - [BasicLuisDialog](https://notepad.pw/BasicLuisDialog) and [MessageController](https://notepad.pw/MessagesController).

Comment: @mdrichardson, I am not getting any help form answer below. I have added bot's files in case if they require.

Comment: Is there a public FAQ you used to create your KB so that I can replicate this? What questions cause it to fail?

Comment: Are you able to share all of your code? There is no longer a bot that exists with a BasicLuisDialog.cs. I'd like to make sure I can repro your issue.

Comment: I was able to find what's likely a similar sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-studybot-csharp/tree/master/Qna-Luis-Bot). I added your code to it and I can't get it to throw an error. It keeps saying "No good match found in KB", as it should. Try downloading your bot by going to `Portal > Web App Bot > Build > Download Bot Source Code`, then follow the "Debug" steps in my answer.

Comment: I used my own questions and answers to create KB. You can find all of my code [here](https://github.com/kailash558/azureBuddy). [Here](https://imgur.com/Dqko218) is screenshot of wrong answer and [here](https://imgur.com/JnJS4rd) is screenshot of error `Sorry, my bot code is having an issue` for same question. These questions, `samsung` and `what is samsung`, do not belong to my KB.

Comment: I still can't replicate this, even using your code. Here's my best guesses: 1) One of your QnA endpoints isn't published or you're using the wrong KB ID, or 2) You have too many published KBs in your Free subscription. There's only a couple additional ways I can help you, laid out in the next comments:

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot this further yourself, Try downloading your bot by going to Portal > Web App Bot > Build > Download Bot Source Code, then follow the "Debug" steps in my answer.

Comment: If you want additional help troubleshooting from me, email me all of your bot/luis/qna connection details (appId/pass/hostname/etc) at vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom. Replace the all-caps with the appropriate character, or find my email in my profile.

Comment: @mdrichardson, I have sent you a mail with all connection details. If further anything needed, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regarding [that tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-luis-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-3.0):

> This article uses Bot Framework v3 SDK. Please see this Bot Framework article, if you are interested in Bot Framework v4 SDK version of this information.

It's old and uses V3 of the Bot Framework SDK. I highly, highly recommend building any new bots in V4. Use the [Add natural language understanding tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) instead.

---

`InternalServerError` indicates that there's a problem with your bot code, somewhere.

Here's a few things you can try that are likely causing the issue:

#### Write code that deals with No Answer

The official [QnAMaker Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker) does that [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker/Bots/QnABot.cs#L45):

```cs
// Query QnAMaker for Answer
var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
// If we have an answer, send it to the user
if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response[0].Answer), cancellationToken);
}
// If we don't have an answer, tell that to the user
else
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("No QnA Maker answers were found."), cancellationToken);
}
```

#### Ensure your QnAMaker Service has a `DefaultAnswer`

This is likely only an issue if you set up your bot to get a default non-answer from your QnAMaker Service.

In `Azure Portal > Resource Group > QnA App Service > Configuration` (note: this is NOT your bot's app service; this one is specific to QnAMaker), ensure `DefaultAnswer` is set:

[image]

#### Debug

Assuming that your bot is actually breaking only when and because no QnA Answers were found, those two things should be the only thing you need to troubleshoot. Otherwise, here's how to debug a bot:

**Visual Studio/C#**:

1. In Visual Studio, run your bot by pressing F5 or clicking:

[image]

2. Open your bot in Emulator
3. In Visual Studio, go to `Debug > Windows > Exception Settings`:

[image]

4. In the Exception Settings window, full-check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

[image]

5. In Emulator, do the thing that makes your bot break. The bot should automatically stop when there's an error. Here, I've forced one:

[image]

As you can see, it says `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'` This means that my array, `response` doesn't have a `0`th element because no answers were returned.

Other issues will show other errors. You can usually pinpoint issues fairly easily by reading the error details and doing a web search for the error code if you need additional details.

**VS Code**

1. In VS Code, run your bot by pressing F5 and selecting 'Node.js' (for Node/TypeScript bots) or `.NET Core` (for C# bots):

[image]

2. Open your bot in Emulator
3. In VS Code, open the Debug menu:

[image]

4. Under "BREAKPOINTS", check "All Exceptions" (Note: It's important to run your bot before checking this box because there are *normal* exceptions that occur when the bot starts up):

[image]

5. In Emulator, do the thing that makes your bot break. The bot should automatically stop when there's an error. Here, I've forced one:

[image]

As you can see, it says `Exception has occurred: TypeError    TypeError: Cannot read property 'answer' of undefined` This means that `qnaResults[0]` is undefined, or doesn't exist, which indicates that no answers were returned.

Other issues will show other errors. You can usually pinpoint issues fairly easily by reading the error details and doing a web search for the error code if you need additional details.

Comment: Here is my [BasicLuisDialog](https://notepad.pw/BasicLuisDialog) file and [MessagesController](https://notepad.pw/MessagesController) file.